# make <span> render in one line

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm just fiddling around with jQuery UI. I want a region on my web page to show notifications...however the way jquery demo sites show is not so practical.

The markup on my page goes somewhat like follows:

```
<div id="msgRow">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info"></span><span id="msg">Some message</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" id="close-message"></span>
</div>
```

Problem with the above is the `message icon`, `text`, and the `close icon` all appear in separate lines.

How to make them in the same line?

Ps: fiddle showing how its done jQuery ui way: http://jsfiddle.net/deostroll/EnKNh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them a common class class with css property,display: Inline-Block.

```
.Sameline
{
Display: Inline-Block;
}
```